# Android NDK: "No Implementation found for native" после переименования проекта

Tags: android, android-ndk

Есть проект, в котором используется `NDK`, при переименования пакета получаю ошибку `No Implementation found for native`, переименовала названия функций в .h и .cc файлах, делала `ndk-build` после этого, но ошибка осталась. В чем может быть проблема? Что где еще нужно поменять?

`Application.mk` выглядит так:

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a

APP_STL := gnustl_static

APP_PLATFORM := android-21

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9
```

`Android.mk` выглядит так:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

TENSORFLOW_CFLAGS     := \
  -fstack-protector-strong \
  -fpic \
  -ffunction-sections \
  -funwind-tables \
  -no-canonical-prefixes \
  -fno-canonical-system-headers \
  '-march=armv7-a' \
  '-mfpu=vfpv3-d16' \
  '-mfloat-abi=softfp' \
  -DHAVE_PTHREAD \
  -Wall \
  -Wwrite-strings \
  -Woverloaded-virtual \
  -Wno-sign-compare \
  '-Wno-error=unused-function' \
  '-std=c++11' \
  -fno-exceptions \
  -DEIGEN_AVOID_STL_ARRAY \
  '-mfpu=neon' \
  '-std=c++11' \
  '-DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=0' \
  -DTF_LEAN_BINARY \
  -O2 \
  -Os \
  -frtti \
  -MD \

#-MF \

TENSORFLOW_SRC_FILES := \
    ./imageutils_jni.cc \
    ./jni_utils.cc \
    ./rgb2yuv.cc \
    ./tensorflow_jni.cc \
    ./yuv2rgb.cc \

LOCAL_MODULE    := tensorflow_demo
LOCAL_ARM_MODE  := arm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TENSORFLOW_SRC_FILES)
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := $(TENSORFLOW_CFLAGS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := \
    -Wl,-whole-archive \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libandroid_tensorflow_lib.lo \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libandroid_tensorflow_kernels.lo \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libandroid_tensorflow_lib_lite.lo \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libprotos_all_cc.a \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libprotobuf.a \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libprotobuf_lite.a \
    -Wl,-no-whole-archive \
    $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libgnustl_static.a \
    $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libsupc++.a \
    -landroid \
    -ljnigraphics \
    -llog \
    -lm \
    -z defs \
    -s \
    '-Wl,--icf=all' \
    -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL \
    -lz \
    -static-libgcc \
    -no-canonical-prefixes \
    '-march=armv7-a' \
    -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 \
    -Wl,-S \

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/genfiles \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/external/protobuf \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/external/bazel_tools \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/external/eigen_archive \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/external/protobuf/src \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/external/bazel_tools/tools/cpp/gcc3 \

NDK_MODULE_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Список `*.so` в финальном `apk` файле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашла решение, проблема заключалась в том, что си библиотеки не были включены в процесс сборки проекта, по этому после переименования проекта, проект переставал видеть native функции. Решением данной проблемы было перенести библиотеки в папку app и перенастроить build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

2 версии:

1) Забыли поправить имена компилируемых файлов в мейкфайле `Android.mk`. Проверьте содержимое поля: `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`

2) Что-то не так с интерфейсным *.с* файлом - там где вы декларируете Java функцию, через которую вы работаете с нативными методами. Метод объявленный как `public static native` должен соответствовать сишному интерфейсу с точностью до *naming convention* включающей имя пакета и проч.

Comment: Хм, имена компилируемых файлов не менялись, поэтому я не изменяла их в Android.mk. По поводу второго пункта, названия функций исправлены согласно названия нового пакета.

Comment: Или может LOCAL_SRC_FILES нужно объявлять как-то по-другому?  я добавила в вопрос, как выглядит LOCAL_SRC_FILES в Android.mk.

Comment: Покажите до кучи `Application.mk`

Comment: только что добавила!

Comment: У вас целевая платформа указана только одна: `armeabi-v7a`, а архитектура устройства скорее всего другая. Поставьте `APP_ABI := all`

Comment: Попробовала, та же ошибка

Comment: В финальном APK файле покажите список `*.so` библиотек - в каких каталогах лежат и как называются (переименуйте APK в ZIP и откройте чем нить)

Comment: Обновила вопрос

Comment: В итоге как и говорилось, у вас нативная библиотека собрана только одной архитектуры: `armeabi-v7a`, для остальных архитектур типа `x86` и проч. нет сборок, оттуда и ошибка. Под подозрением флаг компилятора: `-march=armv7-a`

Comment: Так а что нужно сделать, что бы не было ошибки? Убрать флаг компилятора флаг -march=armv7-a ?

Comment: Попробуйте `-march=generic` - почитайте мануалы gcc (не помню точно)

Comment: Изменила  на -march=generic, тоже самое :(

Comment: Девушка, ваша цель добиться генерации нативных либ для всех платформ. Смотрите за составом *.so библиотек, вы же все таки лаки :)

Comment: Что-то пока не получается сгенерировать нативные либы для всех платформ, буду пробовать дальше!

Comment: Мне удалось сгенерировать еще нативные либы  x86, x86_64, это все? или еще какие-то нужно? Ошибка пока все равно осталась.

Comment: На текущий момент список такой: arm64-v8a,  armeabi,  armeabi-v7a,  mips,  mips64,  x86,  x86_64